# Drawing in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am currently working on a project that enables you to draw with touches in a scrollview. The only problem is, it doesn't let me draw to the bottom part of the scrollview. I am thinking it has something to do with `UIGraphicsgetCurrentContext()`. 
Any help will be awesome!
Heres what I have so far

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    //Here
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(1630, 2400), YES, 5);
    __block CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 1620));
    //[contentView.layer renderInContext:context];
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0f);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
    [[ProblemStore sharedProblemStore] mapCurrentSolutionStrokes:^(SolutionStroke *stroke,   NSUInteger strokeNum) {
      [self drawStroke:stroke inContext:context];
    }];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this `drawRect` method is for some `UIView` subclass, you can simplify it:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0f);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
    [[ProblemStore sharedProblemStore] mapCurrentSolutionStrokes:^(SolutionStroke *stroke,   NSUInteger strokeNum) {
        [self drawStroke:stroke inContext:context];
    }];
}
```

You generally use the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` when you want to render some view and retrieve an image with `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`, but you don't generally use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` in your custom view's `drawRect`, itself. I would separate the `drawRect` functionality from the image saving logic (assuming you even need/want the latter).

So, I personally would create a custom view of the appropriate size (e.g. 1,630 x 2,400), add it to the scroll view, and use the above as the `drawRect` for that custom view.

In terms of why your rendition is not drawing down to the bottom of the scroll view, I suspect it's related to your choice of `scale` of `5` for your `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`. Usually you use `1` (non-retina), `2` (retina), or `0` (use the scale from the main screen).

As an aside, you don't need the `__block` qualifier for your `CGContextRef`. You can access the `context` variable without it.